# Ruby/Rails: Instantiate File object from URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I would like to know how to instantiate a `File` object in Ruby from a url (e.g. `http://www.example.com/foo.png`) that can then be passed to other methods. I need to have a valid `File` object, not a `TempFile`. I'm running a Rails app on Heroku, so ideally I would prefer not to save the file to disk as I only need it to be persisted for the duration of an HTTP post request.

Thanks!

Comment: Your requirement for it to be a real file object and for it not to be saved to disk sound contradictory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? It will open a file from a URL and create a new ruby `File` class with its contents.

```
require 'open-uri'
file = File.new(open('http://www.example.com/foo.png'))
```

Comment: I accepted your answer because it solves my core problem, though I think Frederick Cheung is right in saying that it might not be possible to create a `File` object without writing to disk. I realized that I can call `File.close` to delete the file though, which indirectly solves my other requirement of not persisting the file beyond the POST request.